# How to create a restart button for a game in Java Script

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript.

I have been creating a game- which includes the number of goes a person has had to guess a random number.

I have created the button however I am having problems trying to restart the game - making a new random number to be generated and the number of goes to return to 0

```
var randomno =Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 ) + 1;
    let restart = document.getElementById("restart");
    function restartGame(){    
        num();
    }
}
restartGame();
```

This is only a small snippet of my code.

Comment: don't use java tag when question is about javascript. java and javacript are completely different languages

Comment: What does `num()` function do?

Answer (score 1):

You want to assign a click handler to your restart element which is missing from the OP code snippet... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click

```
  document.getElementById("restart").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // restart the game
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix which may or not be optimal for you is to simply refresh the page. Use something like 'location.reload();' to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand you only need to re-assign some variables.

To do that, just put the variable name followed by the equals sign and the new value you want it.

```
var randomno = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 ) + 1;
randomno = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 ) + 1;
```

The second line the variable is being re-assigned.

If you also have a problem of binding an action for your button to call a javascript event(in your case restart the game), please read this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click